# construct POSIX file with variables

Tags: applescript

I can construct a `file` with variables:

```
set filePath to "Macintosh HD:tmp:test.txt"
tell application "Finder"
    delete file filePath
end tell
```

However, same thing doesn’t work for `POSIX file`:

```
set filePath to "/tmp/test.txt"
tell application "Finder"
    delete POSIX file filePath
end tell
```

It says “can’t get POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt"” (-1728). The syntax looks correct, because it works when I use string literal instead of variable:

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt"
end tell
```

I’m running scripts with `osascript foobar.applescript` in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Big Sur.

```
set filePath to "/tmp/test.txt"
tell application "Finder"
    delete filePath as POSIX file
end tell
```

This also works for me…

```
set filePath to POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt"
tell application "Finder"
    delete filePath
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! Constructing the object with `as` operator indeed works, but do you know why the syntax `POSIX file filePath` doesn’t work as the parameter to `delete` command? It even works when I create a variable, like `set pFile to POSIX file filePath`.